# PyPy memory leak with custom C++ extension?

Tags: python, c++, pypy, python-extensions

I am trying to write a C++ extension with support for CPython and PyPy.

My extension involves creating some custom types that support the call interface.

However, I appear to be getting memory leaks in PyPy when I raise Python exceptions. I am not getting any memory leaks with regular CPython.

I have isolated the leaking code, with a corresponding test in https://github.com/Lalaland/memoryleak_example. Run make to build the code and then test it by either running python test.py or pypy test.py

My extension class is the following:

```cpp
struct custom_function {
    PyObject_HEAD
};

PyObject* custom_call(PyObject *self, PyObject *args, PyObject *kwargs) {
    std::cout << "Calling custom function with except, simpler" << std::endl;

    PyErr_SetString(PyExc_SystemError, "Fancier exception for custom fancy func");
    return nullptr;
};

PyTypeObject custom_function_type = {
    PyVarObject_HEAD_INIT(NULL, 0)
    .tp_name = "custom_function",
    .tp_basicsize = sizeof(custom_function),
    .tp_itemsize = 0,
    .tp_call = custom_call,
    .tp_flags = Py_TPFLAGS_DEFAULT,
    .tp_doc = PyDoc_STR("Custom function type"),
    .tp_new = PyType_GenericNew,
};
```

My memory leak detection code (using weakref) is:

```py
import helloworld as m
import gc
import weakref

class ExampleClass:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

def simple_test(f):
    it = ExampleClass()
    a = weakref.ref(it)
    try:
        f(it)
    except Exception as e:
        print("Got exception!", e)
        del e

    assert a() is not None
    del it
    gc.collect()
    assert a() is None

simple_test(m.custom_fancy_func)
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, looks like this is a bug in PyPy: https://foss.heptapod.net/pypy/pypy/-/issues/3854